# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url' error in function

Tags: python, selenium

Normally I can work get method. But, when ı put get method in my function I get an error message. Also Im looked at a python selenium videos and that guy never got an error. Im using same code but I got this error. How can I solve this problem?
My ide:Pycharm
my code:

```
from instagramuserinfo import username, password
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
class Instagram:
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome
        self.username=username
        self.password=password
    def signIn(self):
        self.browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
        usernameInput=self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input')
        passwordInput=self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input')
        usernameInput.send_keys(self.username)
        passwordInput.send_keys(self.password)
        passwordInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(3)
instagram=Instagram(username,password)
instagram.signIn() 

-----------------------------------------------
error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Turkmen/Desktop/pythonkursbtk/selenium/insta.py", line 19, in <module>
    instagram.signIn()
  File "C:/Users/Turkmen/Desktop/pythonkursbtk/selenium/insta.py", line 11, in signIn
    self.browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

Comment: You forgot brackets?
`self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()`

Comment: Yes. Solved. Thanks.

Comment: Please consider marking your question as resolved using the green check mark  instead of changing the title of the question.

Comment: Okey no answer yet thats why ım dont marking my question as resolved. But ım send a answer and ı will marking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot brackets:

```py
self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```